# Email Password Expiry Reminder to Multiple Users

Tags: powershell

So, I we have a few users that their computers are not on the domain. One of the annoying things about that is windows will not notify them that their domain password is expired obviously. So I decided I was going to put together a little script using powershell in windows that checks AD to see when their password expires and then if it's about to expire in 3 days to send the user an email to notify them that they should change their password.

I have it set up right now to look at the users distinguished name to pull all the necessary information. but I can only do that for one person, I need to look at two user's distinguished names and send each of them an email when their password is about to expire. I tried creating another $DN variable that I could put the other Distinguished name into and put `get-aduser -searchbase $DN, $DN2` but that didn't work for me. Probably was a dumb thing to try, but not sure the syntax needed to accomplish this. Below is my code.

```
$smtpServer="smtp.office365.com" # Office 365 official smtp server 
$expireindays = 100 # number of days for password to expire  
$from =  # email from  
#$logging = "$true" # Set to Disabled to Disable Logging 
$logFile = "c:\Scripts\PasswordChangeNotification.csv" # ie. c:\Scripts\PasswordChangeNotification.csv 
#$testing = "Disabled" # Set to Disabled to Email Users 
$testRecipient =   
$date = Get-Date -format ddMMyyyy
$DN = "Distinguished name here"
# Add EMAIL Function 
Function EMAIL{ 

    Param( 
        $emailSmtpServer = $smtpServer,   #change to your SMTP server 
        $emailSmtpServerPort = 587, 
        $emailSmtpUser = "User"
        $emailSmtpPass = "Password",   #Password for Send from email account 
        $emailFrom = "email@domain.com",   #Email account you want to send from 
        $emailTo, 
        $emailAttachment, 
        $emailSubject, 
        $emailBody 
    ) 
    Process{ 

    $emailMessage = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage( $emailFrom , $emailTo ) 
    $emailMessage.Subject = $emailSubject 
    $emailMessage.IsBodyHtml = $true 
    $emailMessage.Priority = [System.Net.Mail.MailPriority]::High 
    $emailMessage.Body = $emailBody 

    $SMTPClient = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient( $emailSmtpServer , $emailSmtpServerPort ) 
    $SMTPClient.EnableSsl = $true 
    $SMTPClient.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential( $emailSmtpUser , $emailSmtpPass ); 

    $SMTPClient.Send( $emailMessage ) 
    } 
} 

# Get Users From AD who are Enabled, Passwords Expire and are Not Currently Expired 
Import-Module ActiveDirectory 
$users = get-aduser -SearchBase $DN -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress |where {$_.Enabled -eq "True"} | where { $_.PasswordNeverExpires -eq $false } | where { $_.passwordexpired -eq $false }
$DefaultmaxPasswordAge = (Get-ADDefaultDomainPasswordPolicy).MaxPasswordAge

# Process Each User for Password Expiry 
foreach ($user in $users) 
{ 
    $Name = $user.Name 
    $emailaddress = $user.emailaddress 
    $passwordSetDate = $user.PasswordLastSet 
    $PasswordPol = (Get-AduserResultantPasswordPolicy $user) 
    # Check for Fine Grained Password 
    if (($PasswordPol) -ne $null) 
    { 
        $maxPasswordAge = ($PasswordPol).MaxPasswordAge 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        # No FGP set to Domain Default 
        $maxPasswordAge = $DefaultmaxPasswordAge 
    } 

    $expireson = $passwordsetdate + $maxPasswordAge 
    $today = (get-date) 
    $daystoexpire = (New-TimeSpan -Start $today -End $Expireson).Days 

    # Set Greeting based on Number of Days to Expiry. 

    # Check Number of Days to Expiry 
    $messageDays = $daystoexpire 

    if (($messageDays) -ge "1") 
    { 
        $messageDays = "in " + "$daystoexpire" + " days." 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        $messageDays = "today." 
    } 

    # Email Subject Set Here 
    $subject="Your password will expire $messageDays" 

    # Email Body Set Here, Note You can use HTML, including Images. 
    $body ="     
    <p>Dear $name,<br></P><br> 
    <p>Your domain password will expire $messageDays<br><br> 
    Please change your password before it expires.<br></P><br><br> 
    <p>Thanks, <br>

    } # End Send Message 

} # End User Processing  
# End
```

I am just trying to get some insight on how I could modify my code to use two Distinguished names instead of just the one. I'm sure this isn't the best way to do this, but I'm not too good with coding yet. Hopefully this all makes sense, I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, you can store the DN values in an array `$DNs` and process each element of the array. The two expressions inside of the parentheses differ by only the `$DN` variables that you supply. Using a `Foreach` loop slightly performs better than piping to `ForEach-Object`, but in your case it will be negligible.

```
$users = Foreach ($DN in $DNs) {
  get-aduser -SearchBase $DN -filter {
  Enabled -eq "True" -and 
  PasswordNeverExpires -eq "False" -and 
  passwordexpired -eq "False" 
  } -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress)
```

There are added benefits of doing it this way:

- Removal of the `Where-Object`: `Get-ADUser` has its own filter as a parameter that can dramatically increase performance over using `where` in certain queries. It should be faster for you here as the number of returned users from the `Get-ADUser` query increases.

Comment: Thank you for your input, sorry I just barely saw your post. So if I expand and start adding more users to my script would it be better to use a loop then?

Comment: Use loops when you are iterating through data and don't know how many times you may have to iterate. Loops in your case allow your code to be more dynamic. Looping through two strings isn't going to matter at all speed-wise. It is just something to consider when designing scripts, e.g. there could be a tradeoff between running `Get-ADUser` at every iteration vs. just doing that once and looping through the result. You should replace `where` clauses with `-filter` clauses where you can. `Where` is much slower and becomes more apparent when your `Get-ADUser` returns large numbers of objects.

Comment: Adding to the `where` removal, is the fact that not all AD attributes are indexed. Some will return data extremely fast using `-filter` and some will be slower. You should test different designs if performance matters to you. It's difficult to use the word "always" for every scenario.

Comment: ahh okay, sounds good... I was messing around with your suggested bit of code and I'm getting an error that says ```Method invocation failed because [Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser] does not contain a method named 'op_Addition'.``` I'm guessing the op_addition is talking about adding the two together? I was reading that I need to add ``$users = @()`` ... but that hasn't worked for me. any ideas? Thanks a ton!

Comment: Maybe it is a version issue or how you have declared $users elsewhere in the script. I've tested this only on version 5.1 and 5.0. Declaring `$users` like you say should work too.

Comment: hmm weird. I just checked and I am on version 5.1... here's something different, I just run ``get-aduser -SearchBase $DN1 -filter * -properties Name, PasswordNeverExpires, PasswordExpired, PasswordLastSet, EmailAddress`` and it tells me ``Get-ADUser : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'SearchBase'. The argument is null. Provide a valid value for the argument, and then try running the command again.`` I am running ``$DN1`` in the SearchBase parameter. $DN1 just has a specific users distinguished name in it. It was working just fine earlier, I don't know what changed. Dang.

Comment: I actually got by that error, I don't know what the problem is but if I just directly put in the Distinguished name as the argument for the Searchbase parameter it works. But i still have the ``op_Addition`` error

Comment: It is possible your user objects don't all have the same attributes present at output and is throwing that error. I only tested with a subset of users. If that is the case, then just ignore the `+` syntax. The reduction of `where` is still a good thing to do.

Comment: I appreciate your help! i think i got it. I originally had the ``Users = @() ``separate, which was not making it work. I'm sure you could of told me that haha (durr). It didn't work until I put it like this: ``$users =@(get-aduser -searchbase "DN"....`` seems to work like a charm now.

Answer (score 0):

Got it!!

I changed $DN to: 
`$DN = "Distinguished name","Distinguished name"`
then changed my get-aduser code to:
`$users= $DN | ForEach-Objects {get-aduser -SearchBase $PSItem -filter * .....`

thanks,